# Module 'net_rim_bb_browser_field2_api" not found

Tags: blackberry

When i execute my program on 9800, no error found. but i can't execute other simulator. it throws ""Module 'net_rim_bb_browser_field2_api' not found"" error.  how to correct it. or what to change on my coding to execute html content .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest a factory reset of your mobile phone - it sounds as if it's missing a critical RIM library. Also, make sure the OS is 5.0 or above, browser_field2 does not exist prior to 5.0.

Comment: Hi.. thank u for your reply.. Suppose if we execute html content on os less then 5.0. which field use instead of browserfield.. pls reply me.. I'm waiting for ur reply....